# Cordova - How to hide asset folder in .apk?

Tags: android, cordova, directory, apk, assets

I change my *.apk* file to *.zip*  and open it on WinRAR. The problem is *assets* folder is showing so my JS and HTML files are shown. I am using Cordova to develop my app.

How can I hide the assets from the *.apk*?

Comment: You cannot serve assets to the client without letting the client see the assets

Comment: I wrote this tutorial for Ionic Framework, but it can be applied to Phonegap as well.  http://ionicframework.com/blog/minifying-your-source-code/

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't have the assets on the *.apk*, how could they be in the device when you install the app? Of course those need to be available and as it says already on the [security guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_security_index.md.html#Security%20Guide) of Cordova:

> **Do not assume that your source code is secure**
>
> Since a Cordova application is built from HTML and JavaScript assets that get packaged in a native container, you should not consider your code to be secure. It is possible to reverse engineer a Cordova application.

After installing the app on the device, you are of course allowed to download the assets from online and even store them for offline usage with something like [File plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file), but that is completely different case and maybe not even what you wish to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cordova - How to hide asset folder in .apk

1)Encrypted all Cordova assets files. 
2)Decrypt the files and move to the internal storage during runtime.
3)Access your assets files from internal storage( this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()).
Following these things will keep your file and method calling safe as they are accessible only 
to internal storage.

Replace launchUrl "android_asset" to "data/data/io.cordova.hellocordova/files/"

Example: modify the dev source.
1)  "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";   to  Replace     
    "file:///data/data/io.cordova.hellocordova/files/www/index.html";

2) "file:///android_asset/www/index.html"; to Replace  
   "file:///data/data/io.cordova.hellocordova/files/www/index.html";
```